# Check for values in range and select these on listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have an automatically generated listbox with checkboxes. I now want this listbox to check if certain values appear in a range and select these on the listbox.

How do I do this?

I have the following code set up to generate the listbox with values:

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 
    Dim lbtarget As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim curColumn   As Long
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    
        curColumn = 1
        LastRow = Worksheets("Hidden_Classes").Cells(Rows.Count, curColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    'Set reference to the range of data to be filled
        Set rngSource = Worksheets("Hidden_Classes").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
   
    'Fill the listbox
        Set lbtarget = Me.lstCheckBoxes
        With lbtarget
          .ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
          .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
     'Insert the range of data supplied
          .List = rngSource.Value
        End With   
End Sub
```

The items I need to be selected on the listbox appear on the folowing Range:

```
Worksheets("Hidden_Classes").Range("P2:P15")
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. See my Edit.

Comment: Does the values in the `A` column and `P` column are in the same order? Do you know how to use `for... next` loop and `Selected` property of ListBox?

Comment: They are in the same order, yes. I know how to use for...next. I do not know slected though.

Comment: Then what stops you to loop through the values on `A` column (ListBox) and compare them with values in `P` column (you'll need second loop or value returned by `VLookup` WorksheeFunction)?

Comment: Cause I don’t know how.

Comment: I’m trying to store the previous selection when you open the form, the previous selection still stands. Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, you have to loop through the items in a ListBox and the values in the column `P`.

```
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim SecondLastRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

Set wsh = Worksheets("Hidden_Classes")

'change your code here to use [wsh] variable instead of [Worksheets("Hidden_Classes")]

'add below lines right after [End With]

SecondLastRow = wsh.Range("P" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 0 To lbtarget.ListCount -1
    For j = 2 To SecondLastRow
        If wsh.Range("A" & i+2) = wsh.Range("P" & j) Then
            lbtarget.Selected(i) = True
            Exit For 'value has been found and selected, you can skip second [for] loop
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you so much. I did not yet know the exit for function, will come in useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy, try:

```
For i=2 to LastRow

  'Customize your condition for adding them to the listbox or just skip the IF if you want to add them all
  If Worksheets("Hidden_Classes").Cells(i,"A") = "Condition" Then
    
    lbtarget.AddItem Worksheets("Hidden_Classes").Cells(i,"A")

  End If

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have been more clear in what I needed. I need the items in the listbox to compare to a range (see edit) and then select the duplicates on the listbox.